# convert or flatten an ndarray of arbitrary shape to a 1D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, flatten

what is the method to convert an array of arbitrary shape to a 1D array in python? I'm looking for something like this

```
my_array = numpy.array( [4,[5,6],[7,8,9]] )
my_array_flattened = [4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

`numpy.flatten('F')` is not working

Comment: Are you sure, you want a ragged array in the first place? This is not supported directly in recent numpy versions. Only as array of lists.

Answer (score 1):

Try `np.hstack`:

```
>>> np.hstack(my_array)
array([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>>>
```